# Failing to trigger a reactive context for both a Session variable and a Collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a [small project](https://github.com/fowles/meteor-crossword) that has a list of boards  on the right and an active board on the left:

```
var updateBoard = function (b) {
  Boards.update(b._id, b)
  Session.set("active-board-id", b._id)
}

Template.controls.boards = function() {
  return Boards.find()
}

Template.controls.events({
  'click .board' : function (evt) {
    updateBoard(this)
  }
})

Template.board.b = function() {
  var b = Boards.findOne(Session.get('active-board-id'))
  return b || Boards.findOne()
}

Template.board.events({
  'click .cell': function (evt) {
    this.value += 1
  },
  'click .board': function (evt) {
    updateBoard(this)
  },
})
```

when you click on a cell in the board, it should increment.  The underlying board in the collection increments (as you can see by clicking on a different board and then back onto the first board), but the visible board does not increment.

I have tried storing the board directly in the session variable and returning that.  When I do this, the visible board increments, but boards in other tabs do not increment with it.  I am looking for a solution that makes edits to the active board immediately visible to all viewers in all tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figures I would solve it moments after posting the questions.  Apparently `findOne` is not registering itself properly switching to `find` solves the problem.

```
Template.board.b = function() {
  var b = Boards.find(Session.get('active-board-id')).fetch()[0]
  //var b = Boards.findOne(Session.get('active-board-id'))
  return b || Boards.findOne()
}
```

UPDATE:  This was a bug on the devel train for about one day.  It turns out my timing is just good ;-)